# Creating a method with multiple outputs

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I just can not get this method to work and I'm not sure why.

The error that visual gives me is:

> Error  1   A local variable named 'laborCost' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'laborCost', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

and this is what I am trying to to: 
It just doesn't seem to want me to use the same var inside the method as in the description, but how else would the method know what to return?

```
//adds together any other charges from partsLaborGroupBox this is an output method
private void OtherCharges(TextBox partsTextBox,TextBox laborTextBox, out decimal laborCost, out decimal partsCost)
{
    decimal laborCost = 0m;
    decimal partsCost = 0m;


    //this chain goes through the partsLaborTextBox and checks to see if there is input, if so it gets the input 
    //if input is not valid it will display a message. 
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(partsTextBox.Text))
    {
        if(decimal.TryParse(partsTextBox.Text, out partsCost))
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid input for parts");
        }
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(laborTextBox.Text))
    {
        if(decimal.TryParse(laborTextBox.Text, out laborCost))
        {
            //dont need to do anything. 
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid input for labor");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't declare the variable again - it's already declared as a parameter. Just remove the declaration - you are passing as `out` which means modifying the parameter value will modify the reference you passed in to the method call

Comment: Leaving aside the duplicated local variable/parameter names, I'd advise against having multiple return values like this. It is good practice to only return one value. So if you must return two values, wrap them in a Tuple<Decimal> and return them, rather than using out parameters.

Comment: Yeah I saw some mention of Tuple but I haven't gotten that far yet. This is for a class and I'm working on little programming problems at the end of the chapters. The whole program isn't the way I would have written it but the chapter is about methods so I think they are just trying to get us to use methods as much as possible and figure out solutions based on what we already know. Personally I wouldn't have had that method returning two values but that's what they wanted me to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the variable declaration in the top of your method (they are declared in the method definition):

```
 laborCost = 0m;
 partsCost = 0m;
```

You are basically declaring a new variable with the same name in scope. The same error would occur if you write:

```
 int i = 10;
 int i = 40;
```

Comment: Oh yeah..that was so simple. thanks so much for the help and so crazy fast. You guys are all great.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple `out` parameters, but you cannot declare a variable that has the same name as another that is within scope.

So if you have a method with a parameter named `laborCost`, you cannot also define a variable with that name because that would clash. So give your variable or your parameter another name and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the variable declaration inside the method. Means, remove below from your code;

```
decimal laborCost = 0m;
decimal partsCost = 0m;
```

You can't declare variables with the same names which are already declared as method parameters. Still, you can assign values as below.

```
laborCost = 0m;
partsCost = 0m;
```

Further, I think it would be handy if you change the TryParse as below; as you are not going to do anything when the result (of decimal.TryParse) is true.

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(partsTextBox.Text))
    {
        if(!decimal.TryParse(partsTextBox.Text, out partsCost))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid input for parts");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter and local values are having the same name.

use following code,

```
  //adds together any other charges from partsLaborGroupBox this is an output method
    private void OtherCharges(TextBox partsTextBox,TextBox laborTextBox, out decimal laborCost, out decimal partsCost)
    {
        laborCost = 0m;
        partsCost = 0m;


        //this chain goes through the partsLaborTextBox and checks to see if there is input, if so it gets the input 
        //if input is not valid it will display a message. 
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(partsTextBox.Text))
        {
            if(decimal.TryParse(partsTextBox.Text, out partsCost))
            {
                //do nothing
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid input for parts");
            }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(laborTextBox.Text))
        {
            if(decimal.TryParse(laborTextBox.Text, out laborCost))
            {
                //dont need to do anything. 
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid input for labor");
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either change the laborCost declaration in the parameter list or withon the method to a different name, or you need to remove the declaratioin part, and make it a purely assignment,

Something like

```
laborCost = 0m;
partsCost = 0m;
```

withoout the preceding decimal type declaration.